# Calling contract from another on testrpc using web3js

Tags: web3js, testrpc

I want to call method of another contract. But web3js does not support from .sol so I have to hard code the source in a string. How do I deploy two contracts separately but still call the contract inside the other?

Answer (score 2):

You can call an arbitrary contract from another as like the following:

```
contract Client{

    function call(address servAdd){
        Server s = Server(servAdd);
        s.a();
    }
}
contract Server{ 
    function a(){
        FunACalled();
    }
    event FunACalled();
}
```

With `Server s = Server(servAdd);` you can get the referrence to the deployed contract on the address `servAdd` to interact with it.

Comment: Do you get two addresses when you deploy this? I only see one address being generated.

Comment: At least upvote my soluton before asking, man!

Comment: Thanks for replying. Upvoted now. (was reluctant as I already knew that). But do you get two addresses?

Comment: In my example you have to deploy two contracts separately and manually so you naturally have two addresses.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But if you do them separately the Client won't compile. It says Sever not defined. I am getting compile error like that,